# How to assign a new tab with recommended products to product page in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm a complete newbie in Prestashop (and PHP) so sorry if the question will be silly, but I'm trying to solve it by myself and with solid use of Google - with no luck.

**Background:**

I've prepared a simple product recommender in R, based on the frequency of the event where pairs of products occur in the same cart. I put each product's output (recommendation) in a dedicated MySQL table inside the Prestashop database (let's say it's called *ps_recommendations* with a structure like the below).

```
id_product | reco_id_1 | reco_id_2 | reco_id_3 | reco_id_4
```

**Problem:**

I wonder if there's a universal solution to - while visiting a product page - query this additional table by product_id and show the recommendations in the dedicated tab i.e. below the description?

By universal, I mean without developing additional modules, active as default for every product.

I've tried to modify `product.tpl` with code snipped from google, but as I mentioned - no luck.

```
{foreach from=$products item=product}
{if $product.id_product ===$recommendations->id-product}
<a href="{$link->getProductLink({$product.id_product})}">Link</a>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to PrestaShop or PHP, it would be better for you to use one of the native modules as an example. I recommend taking a look at this module:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_categoryproducts

There are a few things/concepts that you need to know.

PrestaShop uses hooks to display additional content in some front office places. This module hooks into `displayFooter`, but it is also a "widget". That means you can display it on the product page wherever you want.

If you are creating a Widget in PrestaShop, you need to implement two methods:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_categoryproducts/blob/dev/ps_categoryproducts.php#L213

and

https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_categoryproducts/blob/dev/ps_categoryproducts.php#L230

As you can see there:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_categoryproducts/blob/dev/ps_categoryproducts.php#L218

The module gets products based on the currently displayed product and its category. You want to use the ID of the product.

After you finish creating your module, you can display it in the hook or by using:

`{widget name="yourmodulename"}`